Работаю с плагином Java в Intellij IDEA: Minecraft Development. Изменил в pom.xml версию на нужную мне, но она не находится в репозитории. Что не так?
Работаю с Minecraft Development с целью создания собственного плагина (для майнкрафта, соответственно). Поскольку при установке плагина на выбор имеются далеко не все версии, по-моему только с 1.12 и до новейшей, мне необходимо было как-то решать данную проблему. Перешерстив весь ру ютуб, решения на свой ответ я не нашел, но нашел на первом англоязычном, автор в свою очередь показал, что достаточно выбрать любую версию из предложенных и в файле pom.xml, который создается автоматически плагином, заменить в кусочке кода

    <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
              <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
    </dependencies>


версию, на необходимую. В данном случае, предоставленном выше, я заменил 1.12 на 1.8.8, но из-за этого пошли ошибки. После достаточно долгого копания в коде, и не только, я сам нашел ответ на свой вопрос, для этого я обратился к репозиторию, откуда берутся эти ядра, и нашел нужное мне. Вот сам репозиторий: https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/#browse/browse:snapshots:org
Нашел нужную мне версию по пути org.spigotmc.1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT и изменил часть кода на:

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
              <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
              <version>1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
              <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>



Я верно указал путь, если обратить внимание, то в этом репозитории есть и версия 1.12-R0.1-SNAPSHOT, и вот когда я пишу ее, то все в порядке, но как только подставляю нужную для себя версию, появляется ошибка Dependency 'org.spigotmc:spigot-api:1.8.8-R0.1-SNAPSHOT' not found, в которой сказано, что нужная мне версия на данном ядре в данном репозитории не найдена. В чем может быть проблема? Долго ломал голову, но по итогу сам не смог решить эту проблему!

Репозитории подключаемы текущим Minecraft Development - Spigot Nexus.
https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/#browse/browse:snapshots:org%2Fspigotmc%2Fspigot-api
И в нём есть ранние версии до 1.12

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

Не понимаю в чём проблемма?

Честно, не знаю, что я сегодня сделал, но ошибки нет)

Видимо ты выставлял всё правильно, просто не нажал магическую кнопочку - обновить зависимости, после изменения pom.xml. А когда сегодня запустил, "Идея" увидела несовпадения в хеше pom.xml и сама обновила зависимости.

Единственное - что я совсем в шоке, неужели кто-то ещё пользуется чем-то ниже 1.12.2. Как-бы 12шка уже сама по себе старая как какашка-мамонта. Что-бы писать плагины ещё на более старое ядро - это как минимум выглядит как легкое извращение.
